# signInWithCustomToken() with Firebase's own tokens

Tags: firebase-authentication

I want to authenticate users on multiple websites via sharing the JWT token. The token was generated originally by firebase, so I assume it is a good and valid token (tested on jwt.io and seems to be fine). I get it by `user.getToken()`.

As I call `signInWithCustomToken(token)` I always get an error `auth/invalid-custom-token` with a message `"The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation."`.

What is strange, it does a HTTP POST request to `https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyCustomToken...` which returns HTTP 400. I have tried on both localhost and also on the https live website... but same result. I'm using Firebase 3.3.

Any ideas, what could be wrong? I was using this feature with the old Firebase.

Comment: So you want to have 2 firebase apps that share the same user base. Is this the case?

Answer (score 3):

You don't provide any code snippets so i am gonna speculate here.

I am assuming you are using node.js to generate the custom token.
Try this in your node script:

```js
    var firebase = require("firebase");
    var adminConfig = {
        serviceAccount: "serviceAccountCredentials.json"
    };
    var adminApp = firebase.initializeApp(adminConfig, 'admin');
    var token = adminApp.auth().createCustomToken('12345678', {
        customField: 'customValue'
    });
```

Then on the client try to signInWithCustomToken(token)
Make sure the client is using the same api key that belongs to the same project where the service account was generated.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not generating the token, the token is generated by Firebase itself and sent to me via the authData (firebase.user). The code snippet is `user.getToken()` in the `onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {...})` callback function. So the token is not custom, it is the Firebase's own token. In Firebase 2.x the function was called `authWithCustomToken` and worked with non-custom (original) tokens.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong: You are trying to sign in with a firebase id token. You cannot do that. This is not a custom token. custom tokens are exchanged for a firebase id token and a refresh token via signInWithCustomToken. You are trying to use the firebase id token to sign in in a separate device i assume. That is not possible.

Comment: In https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getToken nobody calls it "ID token", but you are right, that in https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/verify-id-tokens it is an "ID token". However, if any custom server backend can verify it, why Firebase itself can't. I don't see a difference between them, as the docs say "JWT token used to identify the user to a Firebase service". It used to work in Firebase 2.x. Anyway, thank you for help.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @Tom Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Amsakanna, for some time I did use a simple iframe (with auth.html and auth.js only) with some kind of "security" verifying the domain with which to communicate... through this iframe I've managed to exchange the tokens between the websites. The api was very simple, just get, set, clear... listening for "message" events... but it did not feel very right and maybe it was not even secure, who knows :-/.